# cursor has no method next

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to traverse a collection and update an array for each document.
What am I doing wrong below?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var removeLowestHWScore = function(scores) {
  var lowestHWID = -1;
  for(var i=0;i<scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i].type === 'homework') {
      if (lowestHWID === -1) {
        lowestHWID = i;
      } else if (scores[i].score < scores[lowestHWID].score) {
        lowestHWID = i;
      }
    }
  }
  scores.splice(lowestHWID);
  return scores;
};

var callback = function(err, r) {
  console.log('updated record');
};

var updateScore = function(err, doc) {
  var updatedScores = removeLowestHWScore(doc.scores);
  collection.updateOne({_id:doc._id},
                       {$set: {scores: updatedScores }},
                       callback);
};

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school', function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;

  var collection = db.collection('students');
  var cursor = collection.find({});

  var next = cursor.next();
  while (next) {
    next(updateScore);
    next = cursor.next();
  }
  db.close();
});
```

error

```
/Users/harrymoreno/programming/mongodb/mongo101ForNode/node_modules/mongodb

/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:475
      throw err
            ^
TypeError: Object #<Cursor> has no method 'next'
at     /Users/harrymoreno/programming/mongodb/mongo101ForNode/week03/app.js:35:21
at     /Users/harrymoreno/programming/mongodb/mongo101ForNode/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:472:11
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

sample student

```
{
    "_id" : 137,
    "name" : "Tamika Schildgen",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 4.433956226109692
        },
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 65.50313785402548
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 89.5950384993947
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Of course it will eventually, because your never checking to see if there is a "next" item in the cursor. There are methods on the cursor object that do that, and better ways to write it. The other thing to say here is that the problem you are trying to solve was not meant to be solved by iterating the collection with client side code. There is another MongoDB way to find that lowest score, and the point of the homework assignment is for you to read the documentation and discover that.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for 3 days. I only posted to SO after trying for a long time. I do check the next `var next = cursor.next()` then the while loop checks it. What is the better method? The hint suggested going through each document and assigning a new scores array. They suggested recreating the new array in client-side code.

Comment: There are ways to correct your code. But the main spirit of my comment here was "there is another way to do it". There are clear examples in the driver documentation and also the "tests" on github that can show you how to properly iterate a cursor. But that is not the point of the homework problem here. It really wants you to "query the database" to find that "lowest score". Then you can iterate those results to actually delete the lowest scores found. If we tell you then you don't learn, and the course material will tell you afterwards anyhow.

Comment: I don't get it. They want us to remove the lowest score *for each* student. Thus shouldn't you iterate over every student, drop it's lowest homework score, then update the student? It sounds like you're describing - find the lowest score *in the whole school* and just drop the score from students that have that score. And that can't be what the task is asking.

Comment: The point is **you need to get it**. This is not a chat room so I'm trying to be as succinct as possible. Do you have any RDBMS SQL experience? If so then you already know that you would not try to iterate the whole dataset and test it in code to match your conditions. What you want to happen is to "let the server do the work". What you don't understand right now is that MongoDB is no different in this regard. There is a way to make the server do the work, but you need to read the documentation and find out. That is the point of the question even though you this in not in previous lessons.

Comment: A wise teacher of mine once told me "there is a certain point where you can only teach people to do things and learn them by rote, after that, the only thing that will really help you is to teach you how to learn by yourself". Lot's of information out there to go out and discover. Understand the concepts and then you know what you are looking for. And you will find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED - v.2**

According to the information provided in your last remark abut `mongodb` package version, I've changed to solution to the one you've improved for specific version compliance (using the *1.4.x* node.js mongodb driver) :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var cursor = null,
    collection = null,
    dbSrc = null;

var removeLowestHWScore = function(scores) {
  var lowestHWID = -1;
  for(var i=0;i<scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i].type === 'homework') {
      if (lowestHWID === -1) {
        lowestHWID = i;
      } else if (scores[i].score < scores[lowestHWID].score) {
        lowestHWID = i;
      }
    }
  }
  // scores.splice(lowestHWID);
  if (lowestHWID >= 0)
    scores.splice(lowestHWID, 1);
  return scores;
};

var callback = function(err, r) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('updated record');
  cursor.nextObject(updateScore);
};

var updateScore = function(err, doc) {
  if (err) throw err;

  if (doc === null)
    return dbSrc.close();
  var updatedScores = removeLowestHWScore(doc.scores);
  collection.update({_id:doc._id},
                       {$set: {scores: updatedScores }},
                       callback);
};

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school', function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;

  dbSrc = db;
  collection = db.collection('students');
  cursor = collection.find({});

  cursor.nextObject(updateScore);
});
```

Comment: is `Cursor.each` not deprecated? http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api-docs/

Comment: Yes, you are right about `each` - I didn't know that - but **please find my updated answer** which in my case worked completely properly. I hope it helps. Regards.

Comment: on line 48: `cursor.next(updateScore)` I'm still getting error `TypeError: Object #<Cursor> has no method 'next'
    at /Users/harrymoreno/programming/mongodb/mongo101ForNode/week03/app.js:48:10` any ideas?

Comment: ah I just noticed the `mongodb` package on npm is still 1.4.x not 2.0 So I should be looking at http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/genindex.html

Comment: I changed your solution to comply with the 1.4.x api. If you update the solution to this https://gist.github.com/morenoh149/55fcb1ef00c97203c75f I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: ah if that code worked for you maybe you weren't using the 1.4.x version of the driver? oh well I'm done with this puzzle haha

Comment: Yeah, that's possible :) I've just changed my answer, but could you tell whether the remarks that were present on the end of my previous version are needed for you, or the current version would be enough ?